# High chrony drift with ubuntu 19.04 and intel purley lake (xeon gold 6146)

Tags: 19.04, time

on a newly setup supermicro server using a pair xeon gold 6146 we're having a lot of trouble with time synchronization. The issue is a consistent high drift value:

```bsh
cat /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift 
        19659.271230             1.281228
```

The vendor can reproduce the issue on ubuntu 19.04 but not on redhat 7.2, so they believe that ubuntu  does not support purview lake properly. On our end we did the same setup on an older cpu (an ivy bridge i5 3570) and also found it working just fine.

This is the kernel version we use:

```bsh
uname -r
5.0.0-20-generic
```

This is how we setup chrony/timemaster

```bsh
#first make sure that ntpd and ptpd are removed
sudo apt autoremove ntp
sudo apt autoremove ptpd

#chronyd daemon and chronyc client
sudo apt install chrony
#ptp4l, timemaster and phc2sys
sudo apt install linuxptp

# disable apparmor on chrony
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.chronyd /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.chronyd
```

```bsh
$ cat /etc/linuxptp/timemaster.conf 
# Configuration file for timemaster

[ntp_server 2.debian.pool.ntp.org]
#minpoll 4
#maxpoll 4

#[ptp_domain 0]
#interfaces enp59s0f3
#delay 10e-6

[timemaster]
ntp_program chronyd

[chrony.conf]
include /etc/chrony/chrony.conf

#[ntp.conf]
#includefile /etc/ntp.conf

[ptp4l.conf]

[chronyd]
path /usr/sbin/chronyd

#[ntpd]
#path /usr/sbin/ntpd
#options -u ntp:ntp -g

[phc2sys]
path /usr/sbin/phc2sys

[ptp4l]
path /usr/sbin/ptp4l
```

chronyc output

```bsh
$ chronyc sources -v
210 Number of sources = 12

  .-- Source mode  '^' = server, '=' = peer, '#' = local clock.
 / .- Source state '*' = current synced, '+' = combined , '-' = not combined,
| /   '?' = unreachable, 'x' = time may be in error, '~' = time too variable.
||                                                 .- xxxx [ yyyy ] +/- zzzz
||      Reachability register (octal) -.           |  xxxx = adjusted offset,
||      Log2(Polling interval) --.      |          |  yyyy = measured offset,
||                                \     |          |  zzzz = estimated error.
||                                 |    |           \
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? 10.1.196.1                    0   8     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 10.8.196.1                    0   8     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? golem.canonical.com           0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^+ chilipepper.canonical.com     2   6   377    15  -3140us[-3178us] +/-  124ms
^+ alphyn.canonical.com          2   6   377    14  +4956us[+4956us] +/-  206ms
^+ golem.canonical.com           2   6   377    15  -3504us[-3504us] +/-  118ms
^* 202.29.58.214                 3   6   177    15  -4189us[-4227us] +/-   83ms
^? 2001:3c8:1501:65::1501:11     0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? clock.kku.ac.th               0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? 2401:5700:100:503::1813       0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^? ntp1.cpe.rmutt.ac.th          0   6     0     -     +0ns[   +0ns] +/-    0ns
^+ 202.29.58.130                 2   6    37    26  +4447us[+4406us] +/-   48ms
```

Comment: we "solved" the problem by downgrading to ubuntu 16.04, using kernel `4.4.0-157-generic`